# Dbus issues unable to connect

Tags: linux, apache-httpd, d-bus

I am trying to restart httpd but getting below error

```
$ systemctl restart httpd
Error getting authority: Error initializing authority: Could not connect: No such file or directory (g-io-error-quark, 1)
```

Upon investigation got to know its a dbus issue, trying rest dbus but getting same error as above. Upon checking /var/log/messages i am getting below errors :

```
<info>  [1559812709.0738] bus-manager: could not connect to the system bus (Could not connect: No such file or directory); only the private D-Bus socket will be available
Jun  6 14:48:32 db1 NetworkManager[329115]: <info>  [1559812712.0731] bus-manager: could not connect to the system bus (Could not connect: No such file or directory); only the private D-Bus socket will be available

$ cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 (Core)
```

Notes : `/var` and `/` is in same partition , also i am unable restart NetworkManager

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem deleting `/var/run` by mistake.

Solved re-creating the link:

```
ln -s /run/dbus /var/run/dbus
```

#### Sources

[bwrap: Can't make symlink at /var/run: File exists · Issue #2200 · flatpak/flatpak](https://github.com/flatpak/flatpak/issues/2200)